# iOS Shortcuts feed Siri command via text input

Tags: ios, siri, shortcuts-app

For my “drive to work” shortcut I would like to continue playing whatever podcast I last listened to. There isn’t a shortcut for this so I have to say “hey Siri play podcasts” which achieves the above.

Is there a way to pass that string to Siri so she executes it automatically in a shortcut, rather than having to say it out loud?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to add existing Siri commands to shortcuts. Siri Shortcuts doesn't support Podcasts actions either.